# What is a name of a technique of deduplicating and summarising of logs?

Tags: logging

So for example, you have a stream of logs coming in somewhere (a syslog server, forwarded Windows event logs, "Typical Poor Sysadmin's Mailbox", a Splunk indexer, whatever...)
Imagine this stream of unsorted, unfiltered logs, some are unique and will only happen once a day:
`5 Feb 2014 cake: Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception. Backtrace: ....`
Others will be like an avalanche:
`smbd/server.c:open_sockets_smbd(491)  Reloading services after SIGHUP : 1 Time(s)`
`smbd/server.c:open_sockets_smbd(491)  Reloading services after SIGHUP : 2 Time(s)`
(and another 100 times)

What is a technique of de-duplicating and summarising of logs called?
Something that takes all of the above stream and makes a clean summary:

*Critical errors:*
cake 
`Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception. Backtrace: ....`

*Frequent unknown logs:*
someserver `smbd/server.c:open_sockets_smbd(491)  Reloading services after SIGHUP : X Time(s)` (repeated 100 times)
someotherserver `apache GET /some/imaginary/example` (repeated 35 times)

and so on

Answer (score 1):

Typically that is functionality found in all [log analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log_analysis) and [log management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log_management_and_intelligence) tools, which are the terms I would expect to describe the process of converting of machine generated data into intelligence.

If you want to reduce the amount of data that you store even before analysis reduces it manageable reports:

most software comes with configuration switches reducing the amount and verbosity of log messages.

rsyslog offers the  [$RepeatedMsgReduction](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsconf1_repeatedmsgreduction.html) configuration switch, which turns such duplicate messages into one by logging "Last line repeated n times".

If you're using rsyslog you also have the option to [filter](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog_conf_filter.html) messages quite easily. A basic example to discard messages is this one:

```
# /etc/rsyslog.cof 
# These rules filter messages:
:msg, contains, "smbd/server.c:open_sockets_smbd" ~
```

The tilde `~` is the instruction to discard messages containing the string "smbd/server.c:open_sockets_smbd".

Comment: What about slightly more smart toolset that would allow to do the reduction by ignoring some parts of log messages?